# Cannot import data into pdf checkbox using iText

Tags: .net, vb.net, combobox, itext, itext7

We are using itext in Vb .net we are importing data from an excel spreadsheet and filling in the fields from the spreadsheet. We get everything except for the checkboxes, we are not sure how to handle checking them(They are Either Yes/No )

The internet says to use GetAppearanceState, but not working with our code, We are using iTExt7

```
Private Sub ListFieldNames()

    src = "C:\GR_Templates\xxxForm.pdf"
    dest = "c:\GR_xxx\" & "-" & "-Return" & ".pdf"   '& docName &
    reader = New PdfReader(src)
    writer = New PdfWriter(dest)
    pdfDoc = New PdfDocument(reader, writer)
    form = Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, True)

    fields = form.GetFormFields

End Sub
```

Other Code

```
reader = New PdfReader(src)
reader.SetUnethicalReading(True)

writer = New PdfWriter(dest)
pdfDoc = New PdfDocument(reader, writer)
form = Forms.PdfAcroForm.GetAcroForm(pdfDoc, True)

fields = form.GetFormFields

Dim toSet As PdfFormField = Nothing
For ncol = 0 To dGridView.ColumnCount - 1

    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, PdfFormField) In fields

        v1 = kvp.Key
        If v1 = (headerList(ncol + 1)) Then
            If dGridView(nCol, nRow).Value Is System.DBNull.Value Then
                dGridView(nCol, nRow).Value = ""
            End If
            nVal = dGridView(ncol, nRow).Value

            fields.TryGetValue(v1, toSet)

            toSet.SetValue(nVal)
            If IsNumeric(nVal) And chkSARS.Checked = False Then
                toSet.SetJustification(PdfFormField.ALIGN_RIGHT)
            End If

        End If

    Next

Next ncol

pdfDoc.Close()
```

Comment: Am I right that you cannot get the value of some checkboxes? could you share your pdf then?

Comment: No , i cannot share the pdf as it has confidential information. It does have fields(checkboxes)  Of the same name, One give answer of yes, the other No.

Comment: I have added some code in the original post, showing how i get field names

Comment: If the field in question `toSet` indeed is a check box or radio button, `toSet.GetAppearanceStates` will return the names of the different appearance states. Try them. If that doesn't work, please share the PDF. If you cannot share the PDF, create a different PDF with the same issue and share that file. If you cannot create such a PDF, the issue is clearly specific to your original PDF, so without sharing it you cannot expect any help.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T26jPJ-K7H0ILEb3Ngi_RlK2Y5xuCs4-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: see the file, i have deleted most of it, i have managed to use the GetAppearances but not sure how to set them, Do we just set the value like all the other fields, or have to say something like, If toset.type=checkbox then ..do some code??

Comment: I am getting the value of the checkboxes(Off,Yes,No), I am just not sure how to set. I am setting the same as other text fields, or is there another way. The checkboxes have identical field names. Do we need to set the same field to set, or As it shows for each individual check box, (checkboxname.1 or chechboxname.2)